# how to read log file from within a grails application?

Tags: grails

Grails puts logs files in logs directory. I am wondering how can i read the file from within a grails application.

How can i access the path of a particular log file inside logs directory that i want to read using java file handling libraries?

Lets say the name of the logfile that i want to read is logfile.txt which is inside logs directory of the grails application. I want to read this file line by line from within a grails application.

I appreciate any help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can read your file using below code in grails.

```
def fileData = new File("/logs/logfile.txt")
Println "The file is :" + fileData.text
```